Problems with the group and permissions assigned to a file when creating it from a Windows client on a share in SAMBA AD as a file server
I have created a SAMBA AD Server, with a SAMBA member as File Server. I manage it with a Windows client through RSAT. After creating the resources in smb.conf, assigning the setgid to its corresponding folder so that everything created in it is from the same group, the following happens. When a user logs in with a Windows client and accesses the resource that has permissions, and creates a file in it, the group that assigns said file is not the one in the group, indicated by setgid... does anyone know why this happens?
I have tried with specifications such as 'force group' and several in smb.conf but it has no influence.
